# Can somebody help me figure out what this code mean?

Tags: typescript

In .ts file I have a line of code :

```
var ctrlClass = window["Ctrls"]["Base"]["DBController"]["Grid"];
```

And on another line:

```
return window["Storages"];
```

What is the meaning of `window[" "]`? What do these two lines of code mean?

Comment: Put a `console.log(window)` and inspect the console for that object.

Answer (score 1):

Its a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) which can use a string for the property name.

```
window["Ctrls"]["Base"]["DBController"]["Grid"];
```

Is similar to

```
window.Ctrls.Base.DBController.Grid
```

This is specific to JavaScript and as TypeScript is a super set of JavaScript it also applies there.

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors):

> ## Property accessors
>
> Property accessors provide access to an object's properties by using the dot notation or the bracket notation.
>
> ### Syntax
>
> ```
> object.property
> object["property"]
> ```

---

If you are asking what is the [window](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp) object then see [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp) on that object.

Comment: Is this use the LocalStorage ?

Comment: @SHANKEVIN - if you looked at the documentation of [window](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp) you will see there is no property named `Storages` (as in your question). If you want the local storage look in the documentation for the appropriate property (its there, click on the link, the properties are in alphabetical order).

Comment: SO If I  use the code "new window["Ctrls"]["Base"]["DBController"]["Grid"]. That means I  create a new object and add it to window object? @Igor